# Is static concept equivalent to pass by reference concept

Tags: c, static, pass-by-reference

After some thought.

The **static** keyword in the case of variables provides the variable with a **static location** in the memory even after the function called is **ended**

While **passing by reference** , means that you are passing a pointer to a function , hence the variable **remains** in the memory after the function is ended.

Is that right or there is other difference I didn't notice?

Comment: One difference is that the variable whose address you are passing to the called function can have either of `auto` or `static` storage.

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild I didn't get it !

Comment: Regarding `static` what it does differs depending on context. For example, a function-local `static` variable behaves differently from a file-global `static` variable. And C doesn't have pass-by-reference semantics.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : you said "global static variable", May I ask why to use a static with global variable , while "global" is just enough ?

Comment: @MohamedElShenawy Linking and visibility while linking: A global static variable is local to the [*translation unit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) the variable is defined in, and can't be used by other translation units.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That is a new piece of information to me , Thank you for saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is, that a `static` variable is private to the function. It cannot be modified from the outside, so the function can use `static` variables to preserve some internal state between calls. The caller has no control on a `static` variable.

When you pass something by reference, it is the caller that decides which object to pass. It can be a different one on each call to the function. The function, however, has no control over the object other than that it can modify it during a single call. It especially has no control on the lifetime of the reference passed object; that is entirely up to the caller. As such, referenced passed objects are either used to

- avoid a copy of a large object
- return a second value (the function initializes the object)
- for object oriented programming

The last point comes closest to saving internal state in a `static` variable, but it allows the caller to use any number of different objects whereas the `static` variable guarantees that there is only one.